# SAP Fiori MyInbox with SWFVISU Webdynpro can't use DYNPARAM

Tags: abap, sap-fiori

I'm using SAP Fiori MyInbox. On specific Task I want to open a Webdynpro Application with a custom parameter (an Id which is not Workitem-Id), which is needed by the Webdynpro. So I thougt I can use SWFVISU configuration and so I did the following:

[image]

If I use the "Open Task" Button in the MyInbox it tries to open the Webdynpro Application. Then I'm getting:
[image]

I'm using the Parameter from the Task-Container of the corresponding Task. Also tried a Parameter from the Workflow-Container with same result. If I use a hardcoded Id for the Parameter like *ESCALATION_FORM=00555234232394023* it works as expected.

Someone has an idea!?

Comment: any ST22 entry for this error? The error sounds like a type conversion issue (value not allowed)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For visualization type "ABAP WebDynpro" only "DYNPARAM WI_ID=${item.externalId}" is supported, where ${item.externalId} is replaced with the work item ID.

The visualization type “My Inbox Generic Application” can be used to configure any unrestricted URL (with parameters).
A detailed description on how the URL is created and which parameters are used is available in SAP note 2178368.